# Custom number formatting

Tags: c#, formatting

I need to format a string in a custom number with the mask: "0000000-00.0000.0.00.0000".

I try this code:

```
string test = string.Format("{0:0000000-00.0000.0.00.0000}", 00014414720108190006);
```

The output is: "144147201081900-06,00000000000"

What is the best way to obtain a "0001441-47.2010.8.19.0006" in this example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to escape the dots because they are usually interpreted as custom format specifiers. Use the following format string and it will work. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierEscape) for reference.

```
@"{0:0000000-00\.0000\.0\.00\.0000}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add \ before every full stop otherwise they are interpreted as different formating.